# What's the difference between onload () and Onshow () in small program development?

Tags: wechat

- If you want to refresh every time you enter this page, should you choose `Onshow ()`?

Answer (score 0):

The docs desciptions：
OnLoad is running which your Page first load.
OnShow is running which your Page scripts loaded which includes your Page first load ,back to the Page from other Pages ,back form calling or back from other apps and miniprograms

Comment: It's wechat docs about it.https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/app-service/page-life-cycle.html